# How to use the gallery formatter settings in a display suite code field?

Tags: media, display-suite

I am using the [gallery formatter](http://drupal.org/project/galleryformatter) module to format photo galleries.

To satisfy a requirement I need to create a `Display Suite code field` that displays the list of pictures attached to a related node (attached through the [Entity reference](http://drupal.org/project/entityreference) module).

The get the `field_gallery` containing images of the related page I use the following in the code field:

```
<?php 
    $relatedNode = node_load($entity->field_related_page['und']['0']['target_id']);
    $field = field_view_field('node', $relatedNode, 'field_gallery', array( 'label'=>'hidden'));
    echo drupal_render($field) ;
?>
```

However this only displays a raw list of images. **I need this list of images to be fomatted by the gallery formatter**.

The formatter should be passed to field_view_field() as an array (instead of `array( 'label'=>'hidden')`) but **how can I get the list of key->values that fill the array?**

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest field slideshow if you havent tried that already.  [Field Slideshow](http://drupal.org/project/field_slideshow)

> Provides a Slideshow formatter for Image fields, using JQuery Cycle
>   plugin.
>
> Compared to Views slideshows, building the slideshow from multiple
>   nodes, this module builds it from a single node, with a multi-valued
>   Image/Media/Field Collection field.

Answer (score 0):

You can try code below:

```
<?php 
    $display = array(
      'label' => 'hidden',
      'type' => 'galleryformatter_default'
    );
    $relatedNode = node_load($entity->field_related_page['und']['0']['target_id']);
    $field = field_view_field('node', $relatedNode, 'field_gallery', $display);
    print drupal_render($field);
?>
```